# How to create a new property in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, properties

I'm new to google apps engine.
I want to have a something like:

```
class demo(db.model)
 user = db.UserProperty() 
 date = db.DateProperty(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
 weekly = SomeNewProperty()
 ...
```

How do I create this "SomeNew" property?
I read some docs about it but didnt understand what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different property types specify the type of the property. You can't easily define your own types (and I don't think that this is what you're after).

Take a look at [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html) to see a list of different property classes.

For example to add a new boolean property `weekly` you'd write:

```
weekly = db.BooleanProperty()
```

If you want a "complex" property, then you can model that as its own model and use a [`ReferenceProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) like this:

```
class WeeklyInfo(db.Model):
   user = db.UserProperty() 
   date = db.DateProperty(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   confirm = db.BooleanProperty()

class Demo(db.Model):
  someData = db.StringProperty()
  weekly = db.ReferenceProperty(WeeklyInfo)
```

Comment: hi. thanks for answering- but i want weekly to be some sort of a class itself. ie weekly should have 3 field -user ,date and confirm -these 3 are from the regular db.???Property()

Comment: TNX- i think this what i need

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `db.Property` to create new types of properties. See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/extending_models.html) for information.